# Tkinter cbox doesn't change var value

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

So, essentially what is going on is I made a password manager that had a password generation part to it, I moved it to a windowed Tkinter program for ease of use.  I got everything down except for the check box, so at first when the function was called it would give me the error that alphabet had empty length so I set alphabet equal to the list with special characters.  After that I tried them with while loops, same result.  (this whole code is a function inside the program that only gets ran when a button is pressed)  I know I could probably fix this issue with the **init** but I was hoping if anyone knew an easier way without rewriting too much.  Here is the edit to make the code simplified.  I used it with a while loop, and got the same result as the if statement.  I get the error that a is not defined in this situation.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def cbox_var():
    while cbox_1 == True:
        a = 10
    while cbox_1 == False:
        a = 20
    print(a)

main = Tk()
cbox_1 = Checkbutton(main, text="yes or no")
cbox_1.pack()
testbutton = Button(main,text="Test", command=cbox_var)
testbutton.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: I know my use of variables is very bad but I am trying to get everything running right for my first program.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. There's not enough code in your question to know what the problem is, and you've left out crucial details such as what type of object `special_characters_cbox` is.

Comment: I created a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code.  It shows that the checkbox is not assigning the variable when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of a checkbutton you must assign one of the special tkinter variables to it. You can then get the value by calling the `get` method on the variable.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def cbox_var():
    checked = cbox_variable.get()
    print("Checked?", checked)

main = tk.Tk()
cbox_variable = tk.BooleanVar()
cbox_1 = tk.Checkbutton(main, variable=cbox_variable, text="yes or no")
cbox_1.pack()
testbutton = tk.Button(main,text="Test", command=cbox_var)
testbutton.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, fixed all my variable issues.